# Cannot use Renderer2 to change attribute of button referenced using ViewChild

Tags: javascript, html, angular, dom

I'm currently trying to change an attribute of a button using Renderer2 but I keep getting an error saying:

**ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'setAttribute' of undefined**

I want to be able to add the disabled attribute to the button when I click it.

I'm using the mat-button component from angular material:
https://material.angular.io/components/button/overview

I've tried logging the value of the button reference to the console and it isn't logging 'undefined'

Here is the button html element:

```
<button #stickButton mat-raised-button color="warn" (click)="onStickButtonClick()">Stick to Bottom</button>
```

Here is the reference and onclick function inside the typescript class:

```
constructor(private renderer: Renderer2){
}

@ViewChild('stickButton', {static: false}) private stickButton: ElementRef;

onStickButtonClick(){
  this.renderer.setAttribute(this.stickButton.nativeElement, 'disabled', '');
}
```

The output I'm hoping for is that the button element becomes like this:

```
<button #stickButton disabled mat-raised-button color="warn" (click)="onStickButtonClick()">Stick to Bottom</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code above would work for a normal button, not a button having a material button directive attached.

The element you are getting with the `ViewChild` is actually of the type `MatButton` which doesn't have a property nativeElement. So what is undefined in your case is

`this.stickButton.nativeElement`.

Since it is a MatButton, you can actually disable the button directly like:

`this.stickButton.disabled = true`

Here is a complete example:

```
export class AppComponent  {
  constructor(){
  }

  @ViewChild('stickButton', {static: false}) private stickButton: MatButton;

  onStickButtonClick(){
    this.stickButton.disabled = true;
  }
}
```

Here is a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ul6cpw)